# How can i make base64 encode a file multiple times and output it in a file?(bash)

Tags: bash, base64

Currently this is my working code. How do I make this better with some output file and file appending. Example output the base64 encode text to sample1.txt, sample2.txt and so on..

Any help is much appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

state=$(<myfiletoencode)
for i in {1..5}; do
   state=$(<<<"$state")
done
echo "$state"
```

Comment: This is quite unclear. Why would you base64-encode something multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to have

```
base64 file > sample1.txt 
base64 file | base64 > sample2.txt
base64 file | base64 | base64 > sample3.txt
...
```

Since you want to have a file for each step, you don't need variables. Just encode the last file to generate the next one:

```
#!/bin/bash
ln myfiletoencode sample0.txt
for i in {1..5}; do
   base64 "sample$((i-1)).txt" > "sample$i.txt"
done
rm sample0.txt
```

Keep in mind that equivalent base64 encodings can be formatted differently. You can add linebreaks whenever you like. Example:

```
$ seq 23 | base64
MQoyCjMKNAo1CjYKNwo4CjkKMTAKMTEKMTIKMTMKMTQKMTUKMTYKMTcKMTgKMTkKMjAKMjEKMjIK
MjMK
$ seq 23 | base64 -w0
MQoyCjMKNAo1CjYKNwo4CjkKMTAKMTEKMTIKMTMKMTQKMTUKMTYKMTcKMTgKMTkKMjAKMjEKMjIKMjMK
```

When you encode this encoding again you get different encodings depending on the formatting (note the different length and suffix `wpNak1LCg==` != `01qTUs=`):

```
$ seq 23 | base64 | base64
TVFveUNqTUtOQW8xQ2pZS053bzRDamtLTVRBS01URUtNVElLTVRNS01UUUtNVFVLTVRZS01UY0tN
VGdLTVRrS01qQUtNakVLTWpJSwpNak1LCg==
$ seq 23 | base64 -w0 | base64
TVFveUNqTUtOQW8xQ2pZS053bzRDamtLTVRBS01URUtNVElLTVRNS01UUUtNVFVLTVRZS01UY0tN
VGdLTVRrS01qQUtNakVLTWpJS01qTUs=
```

Therefore I'd suggest do disable all linebreaks in the output using `base64 -w0`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works just how I wanted to! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Indicative Glad I could help. Please accept this answer (by clicking the checkmark  on the top left of this answer) to close your question.