# Repeated base64 encoding differs from expected result

Tags: bash

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Hack The Box where I have to create a bash code to tell me the number of characters that the thirty-fifth base64 encoding has. I have to enter the answer and the system tells me if it's right or not. The result this code is giving is somehow wrong and I don't know why!

```
var="nef892na9s1p9asn2aJs71nIsm"
COUNTER=1
for counter in {1..40}
do

        var=$(echo $var | base64)

        if [ $COUNTER == 35 ]
        then
                echo $COUNTER
                echo -n "$var" | wc -c
        fi
        COUNTER=$(( COUNTER + 1 ))
done
```

IT'S DONE! This is the code I use to solve the box:

```
var='nef892na9s1p9asn2aJs71nIsm'

for ((counter = 0; counter < 35; ++counter)); do
  var="$(echo "$var" | base64)"
done

echo $var | wc -c
```

The answer is 1197735

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68234076/6770384) helps tracking down the problem. The base64 encoding can be formatted differently. The next encoding depends on this format. Therefore, changing the format has a substantial influence on the outcome.

Comment: @Socowi I don't know the expected result. :)

Comment: why the double counters `COUNTER` and `counter`? (hint: you only need one)  Why the range `{1..40}` if you only want to go to 35? (hint: `{1..35}`); what (wrong) number(s) have you generated so far?

Comment: Do you need `var=$(echo -n $var | base64)` to avoid encoding the trailing newline added by `echo`?

Comment: wrt to comments by Socowi and Jonathan Leffler ... have you been given any details on how to use `base64`, eg, need to use the `-w0` flag? *make sure not to count a trailing \n*?

Comment: You could just do a calculation without using `base64`.  For an input of length N, the output is of length `((N + 2) ÷ 3) ✗ 4` using integer division (4 characters output for every 3 in the input, and 4 more if there are 1 or 2 characters left over).  If you start with 26 characters, you get 36, 48, 64, 88, 120, … for subsequent iterations.  Iterate to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `-w 0` to avoid the default line wrapping in `base64`, in addition to disabling `echo`’s implicit newline with `-n`. Otherwise newlines in your `base64` output will become spaces in the value of `var` and the newline from `echo` will be added into the `base64` encoding.

```sh
var='nef892na9s1p9asn2aJs71nIsm'

for ((counter = 0; counter < 35; ++counter)); do
  var="$(echo -n "$var" | base64 -w 0)"
done

echo "$var"
echo "${#var}"
```

This snippet says that it’s **684940** characters, but I may well be wrong.

Comment: It's wrong! The only information I have is this: The variable "var" is encoded 40 times in the For-Loop. However, we only need the 35th value of it. When this value is reached, the number of characters in the variable "var" should be counted and output.

Comment: Well, the result exactly matches the one you get from the formula mentioned above: `N := 4 * ((N + 2) / 3)`. If you set N to the length of the input and iterate 35 times, you will get that same result. So there may be something wrong about the task and/or its interpretation. For example, why perform 40 iterations for no reason when only 35 are needed? There is quite likely something peculiar about the task that you’re missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var='nef892na9s1p9asn2aJs71nIsm'

for ((counter = 0; counter < 35; ++counter)); do
  var="$(echo "$var" | base64)"
done

echo $var | wc -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this on macOS? While the GNU/Linux version of the base64 command wraps the output after 76 characters by default, the macOS version does not wrap it. I fixed it by adding the "-b 76" option to the base64 command (but no "-n" to the echo command):

```
var=$(echo  $var | base64 -b 76)
```